# Ubuntu 20.04 - rename network interfaces showing in GUI

Tags: networking, 20.04

Currently I have three interfaces:

[image]

how can I rename them so that I know on first sight what they are for?

Comment: Your title says you are using Ubuntu Core 20 but in the question it says 20.04 can you please clear this up. If you just say 20 it could be Ubuntu Core 20 or  Ubuntu 20.04 they are all different.

Comment: Edited my question.

Comment: If it is for device-name https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.link.html